# Count with OData in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have been using odata query in Reactjs, to get the count of the  students, as below:

```
<Fetch url="http://localhost:52484/Students/$count">
    {({ loading, error, data }) => (
       <div>
         {loading}
         {error}
         {data && <div>{console.log(data)}</div>}
       </div>
     )}
</Fetch>
```

But not getting the count in the response.
Here is the response:
[image]

I am consuming ASP.net Web API 2.

Is there a working example of how to use $count with OData in Reactjs?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you share the response?

Comment: @FortyTwo : Have edited and shared the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this worked:

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch("http://localhost:52484/Students/$count")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

It returned just the integer, that is the count of the students! :)